# Click button in Bootstrap modal to get the launching element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

How could you get the button that was originally pressed to open the modal through a button inside the modal?

Html:

```
<button id="opener" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <button type="button" id="targetModalOpener">Button</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#targetModalOpener').closest('.modal')
```

I'd like to somehow get `$('#opener')` through pressing `$('#targetModalOpener')`.

For the purposes of this question I gave the opener an id attribute although it does not have one.

Comment: how could you get the button or the modal?

Comment: Whats the problem??

Comment: It can be done by `$('button[data-target:'+$('#targetModalOpener').closest('.modal').attr('id')+']').html('Hi there');`

Comment: @saAction what if there are multiple buttons with the same data-target?

Comment: @bdoubleu, in that case you need to store last opened model parent in a variable.

Comment: @saAction when the modal closes it automatically returns focus to the launching element so I don't think a variable is necessary.

Comment: Here, don't use `data-target="#myModal"` and use jQuery to open mode by click event, that's how you can get launching element in to variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the button that was originally pressed to open the modal by using [Bootstrap Modal Show Event](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events) and using [activeElement](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_document_activeelement.asp) which in this case is the button who triggered the modal.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var opener;

$('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    opener = document.activeElement;
});

$('.modal button').click(function(){
    console.log(opener);
});

});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
<button id="openerABC" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalABC">Open Modal ABC</button>

<button id="openerXYZ" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalXYZ">Open Modal XYZ</button>

<div id="myModalABC" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button type="button" id="targetModalOpenerABC">Button</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="myModalXYZ" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button type="button" id="targetModalOpenerXYZ">Button</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Okay but I'm trying to get the original opener when the button from inside the modal was pressed, not when the opener is pressed.

Comment: @bdoubleu I see, I edited my answer to fit the requirements. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

According to the modal [events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events) you can get the event **relatedTarget** and save this as a data attribute of button:

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    $('#targetModalOpener').data('id', e.relatedTarget);
});
$('#targetModalOpener').on('click', function(e) {
    var opener = $(this).data('id');
    console.log(opener.outerHTML);
})
```

```js
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    $('#targetModalOpener').data('id', e.relatedTarget);
});
$('#targetModalOpener').on('click', function(e) {
    var opener = $(this).data('id');
    console.log(opener.outerHTML);
    
    
    $('#myModal').modal('hide')
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button id="opener" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal1</button>
<button id="opener2" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal2</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <button type="button" id="targetModalOpener">Button</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```